# Image file upload error: Unable to read image from file () - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, iis, file-upload

Having issues with the intervention Image package for laravel.

I have a simple form which accepts an image, I then take that image and fit it, and move save it to a new location. I then persist the file path into the database.

on my local machine I run xampp with php7 and everything runs fine.

However, when I upload my changes to my remote host, I get this error when submitting the form:

```
NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 21:
Unable to read image from file ().
```

Here is the code which I use:

```
$file = $request->file('profile-picture');

$destinationPath = 'uploads/';

$filename = md5(microtime() . $file->getClientOriginalName()) . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

$path = $destinationPath.$filename;

Image::make($file)->fit(300)->save($path);
```

My remote host is running windows server 2012 with IIS 8.

As I say, this runs perfectly on my local machine with xampp, which leads me to believe that there is some sort of permission issue on my remote host.

I've checked the folder permissions on the '/uploads' folder, and they seem fine as far as I am aware. Could there be an issue with permissions on the temp folder the image first gets uploaded to?

Comment: Can you check for the permission and double check the file type you are uploading.

Comment: the file type is definitely an image, I've tried both .jpg and .png. It wouldn't even get to this code unless laravel classed the uploaded file as an image.

`if ($info === false) {
            throw new \Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException(
                "Unable to read image from file ({$path})."
            );
        }`

that is the block of code from Decoder.php,  specifically, line 21 is `"Unable to read image from file ({$path})."`

Comment: in terms of permissions for the '/uploads' folder, the user: IIS_IUSRS has full control.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was in your file. Did you identify in which line the problem occurs in your code?

Comment: `Image::make($file)->fit(300)->save($path);` seems to be the offending line, looking at other issues similar to this, I assume its the make() function  that's causing the issue. The error that is thrown seems to suggest that the $file variable is empty, as `...from file ()` should include the path of the file in them brackets looking at the Decoder.php file.

Comment: I think you are right. The way to solve this is to debug the code line by line and check the results using dd(), for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a look in the php.ini file to see what the temp folder was set at, it was in C:\Windows\temp

Changed it to somewhere else and that has seemed fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

apk (alpine):

```
apk add imagemagick
```

apt(ubuntu):

```
apt install imagemagick
```